# Regression analysis low R2 value - Result interpretation

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, linear-model, nonlinear-regression

When I run linear regression on my test data I get the following report:

[image]

You can find the test data in [here](http://paste.ofcode.org/33VQKk2X82NnAHQ2uYF2s7K).

The graph of actual vs predicted looks like:
[image]

I would like to know if this is fairly a good fit because summary gives R2 value is 0.43 which says that the variable has no significant linearity. But the avg error percentage is close to 97%.

Should I still keep this results as my analysis?

Comment: Where do you see the 97%?

Comment: I calculated the error difference between actual and predicted at each data point. Then I did an total average error  which was close to 97%.

Comment: @StudentT Exactly. But still the R2 co efficeint signifies a weak correlation between the variables. So was wondering if I should ignore this in this case. I also read few resources where it mentioned that even though the R2 value is low, the results could be still significant.

Comment: Your model is relatively poor, depends on your context. Your model can only explain less than half of the total variation. The p-vaue simply tells you it's not zero. It's indeed not zero because it's about 6 and you have some number of sample size.

Comment: I think you should try to make a plot of the variables. I was trying to do it for you but I couldn't import your data.

Comment: Just for your reference I uploaded the test file as text file and you can download it on  http://expirebox.com/download/5addac42c47a44f80b676b674931b886.html

Comment: @StudentT I have also put up the plot of my data here http://imgur.com/4VXq2yR
Do you think I should use other model for this ? If so could you please suggest me an appropriate one for such test data.

Comment: Insisting on showing zero on the graph just obscures the patterns in the data. What's the ordering in any case? The format is bizarre. A scatter plot with observed and predicted and a reference line of equality is one possibility.

Comment: @NickCox Could you please be kind to put it in lame words for better understanding? Thanks

Comment: I don't think I am using any technical words not in a first course. So, sorry, I don't understand what you don't understand.

Comment: @NickCox What exactly "ordering" refer to in your terms? Kindly bare. I am a beginner.

Comment: The reason for the order of values on the $x$ axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that there is no straight forward answer to your question.

First off, it is unclear what you mean by “significant linearity”.  In OLS the R-squared is a measure of how well you estimates *predict* the data, it is not a useful measure for how linear your model actually is. Examining linearity is traditionally done with regression diagnostics.  I have seen many models with R squared below 1% that appear very much linear (they are just really noisy), and models with R-squared of above 97% that are extremely non-linear (as in spurious time-series regressions).

As far as how good the fit is… everything is relative, and much also depends on what exactly you're looking for.  43% is a huge improvement from 0%.  Perhaps such a model could prove lucrative in the hands of a knowledgeable individual (in finance I have seen people save millions off of models with R-squares of 7 %).  On the other hand, there could also be a very simple improvement to your model that obtains a much higher adjusted R square.

In sum, getting an R squared of 43% with only one regressor would be an earth shattering accomplishment in certain contexts, while in others it would remain unimpressive or of average quality.

It also depends on what exactly you’re looking for.  Notice your coefficient is significant, which under the OLS assumptions, means that you’re independent has a significant effect on your dependent.  If you are interested only in proving a significant relationship exists, than the R-squared does not matter nearly as much.  However, if you are interested in making a model with high predictive precision, the R square matters much more whereas the coefficient significance is not as important.

Comment: Thanks a lot. By significant linearity I mean  the variables have a high correlation. I referred to several resources where most of it stressed on R2 value as the significant factor to measure the strength of correlation between variables. Just to make sure my assumptions are right, I request you kindly refer to image  [here](http://imgur.com/4VXq2yR)   where I plot a sample of my test data. Do you consider this graph as linear from the first impression?

Comment: @SangameshHs It's not helpful to anyone to define "significant" as meaning "high" (your first sentence) and then to use the word to mean something else (your second sentence). Significance in a statistical context refers to the result of a significance test and can be quantified. High is at best a substantive judgement but only meaningful in context. For some purposes $R^2$ of 43% is a success (e.g. much social science); for other purposes it is outrageous failure (e.g. much physical science).

Answer (score 3):

As @Nick Cox mentioned, the statistics have very different interpretation. Just because you can fit a linear-model, it doesn't mean your independent is a good measure of the dependent variable. In your question, you're trying to "force" the model to work.

When you do a regression analysis, in particular a simple regression, it's always a good idea to do a scatter plot. I've done it for you. Please and please when you give data out, do it in a way that people can just copy-and-paste into R. I had to write a parser to parse your data. You were lucky this time.

[image]

Do you think there's a linear regression here? Note that you have a bunch of purchased sales give similar sales prices.

If you draw a straight line that minimises the OLS, the slope won't be zero (obvious graphically). The summary statistic gives a value of about 6, but it's meaningless in this context.

As @Zachary Blumenfeld pointed out, R2 is a measure of the prediction. It's obvious that you can't achieve a very high accuracy here. For example, when the purchased variable is 16.2 the outcome is about 33.5, but the purchased variable is 16.7, the outcome is also 33.5. While there is certainly dependence between the two variables, it's not a linear relationship.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your time and effort.Thanks for sharing your thoughts. It was really informative. I have start working my basics again. Thanks again.